# iPad assets in Universal app on iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios-universal-app, ios8.1, size-classes

I have an app that fully supports iPhone 6 plus. I just converted it into universal app and I observe that iPad is able to catch up all the assets in highest resolution - not sure if it is using @3x version or @2x version. I am wondering if the requirement of putting @2x~ipad assets is redundant, or there will be problems if the app is run on an iPad running iOS 7 ? FYI, I use size classes and storyboards.

Comment: Use an [asset catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)

Comment: Well I am already using it for things like app icon, launch screens, etc. But for other things like buttons, navigation bar images, etc, I do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://github.com/JVillella/ios-screen-sizes) table I made, if you are naming your assets `@2x`, and `@3x` like you mentioned than the iPad will pick `@2x` for iPad 3 and newer. `@3x` does not currently apply to any iPad on the market. Hope that helps.